# When i refresh my pagelist, My items in PageAdapter will be misplaced for a short time

Tags: android, android-pagedlistview

[image]

As above pic show, The items will be misplaced momently while i refresh.

```
 smartRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            mViewModel.observeComposition(ConnectivityUtil.isNetworkReachable(this),mLabelId.toInt(),lifecycleScope).observe(this, Observer {
                mCompositionAdapter.submitList(it)
                smartRefresh.finishRefresh()
            })
        }
```

My Adapter

```
class CompositionsAdapter(context: Context) : PagedListAdapter<CompositionAbstract, CompositionsAdapter.ViewHolder>(CompositionAbstractDiffCallback()) {


    private val mScreenWidth by lazy {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        val windowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
        displayMetrics.widthPixels
    }

    val width by lazy {
        (mScreenWidth - 15.px * 3) / 2
    }
    val height by lazy {
        val srcWidth = 165f.px
        val srcHeight = 155f.px
        width * (srcHeight / srcWidth)
    }


    class ViewHolder(private val binding: HomepageItemGroupCompositionBinding)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: CompositionAbstract) {
            binding.apply {
                composition = item.briefComposition
                itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    ARouter.getInstance().build(HomePageArouterConstants.PATH_AUDIO_PLAYER).withString(HomePageArouterConstants.KEY_ID, item.briefComposition.id).navigation()
                }
                executePendingBindings()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = HomepageItemGroupCompositionBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        binding.imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height.toInt())
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let {
            holder.bind(it)
        }
    }
}
```

My Itemdecoration

```
 class GridSpacingItemDecoration(private val spanCount: Int,
                                    private val verticalSpacing: Int,
                                    private val topSpacing: Int
    ) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {


        override fun getItemOffsets(
                outRect: Rect,
                view: View,
                parent: RecyclerView,
                state: RecyclerView.State
        ) {
            val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)

            if (position / spanCount == 0) {
                outRect.top = topSpacing
            }
            if (position % spanCount == 1) {
                outRect.left = 7.px
            }
            outRect.bottom = verticalSpacing
        }

    }
```

My diffUtil

```
class CompositionAbstractDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CompositionAbstract>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CompositionAbstract, newItem: CompositionAbstract): Boolean {
        return oldItem.briefComposition.id == newItem.briefComposition.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CompositionAbstract, newItem: CompositionAbstract): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

Any ideas for this problem? Thanks for first!

Comment: after refreshing, can you clear the list, set a new one, and notifyDataSetChanged and add a delay of say 200ms before notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @notTdar I have tried, but pagedlist can not be changed and only submit a new pagelist to PageAdapter

Comment: you don't have setters in Adapter? anyway after setting up the list, put a delay of 200ms then call to adapter.notifYDataSetChanged

Comment: @notTdar PageAdapter has a little difference with ListAdapter, Its data is managed by PageList, So i can only invoke ``` mCompositionAdapter.submitList(it)```  to change its data source.

Comment: alright, so once you submit the list, do you call notifyDataSetChanged or something similar?

Comment: @notTdar no need to call notifyDataSetChanged,  PageList will notify adapter change its DataSet

Comment: I think there is a problem with your diffUtil

Comment: hmm, check the diffUtil and "moviePagedList.dataSource.invalidate()" ay option?

Comment: @notTdar  I have edited my post and tried ...dataSource.invalidate(), but not works